# List up all cells values related to one raw as new raw

Tags: excel, vba

I need your support to re-arrange an excel sheet, listing all values in columns to be in new raws.

As is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSlqn.png)

To be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6xoN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Original table]

[image: Result table]

One of the ways is you use loops of repetition to perform the transposition of the data

```
Public Sub transpose()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim resultRow As Integer
    
    
    resultRow = 2
    lastRow = Planilha1.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Planilha1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    startRow = 1
    
    For iRow = startRow To lastRow
        
       For iCol = 2 To lastCol
        'col 7 and 8 = key and value
        Planilha1.Cells(resultRow, 7) = Planilha1.Cells(iRow, 1)
        Planilha1.Cells(resultRow, 8) = Planilha1.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
       Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```